# jQuery on click slide down specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a complete brain melt, but I cannot remember how to get a specific div to do a jQuery `slideDown` on a click event.

This is what I've been trying to do:

```js
$('.content--link').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="content--link" href="#">Click this 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is the content to show for 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="content--link" href="#">Click this 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is the content to show for 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Link to Demo (CodePen)](https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/VJVBEd)

I've done this before, but I'm not sure what I'm not getting correct. I think I need to traverse up and then back down again with `.parents` possibly? Anyways, it's been a day.

Answer (score 4):

Almost, use `$(this).parent().next('.content')`.

**.next()** won't work alone in this situation as it gets the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. `content--link` doesn't have a sibling but it's parent (div.link) does.

https://api.jquery.com/next/

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `parent()` . Use `parent` before `next` to toggle next div.

```js
$('.content--link').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="content--link" href="#">Click this 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is the content to show for 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <div class="link">
    <a class="content--link" href="#">Click this 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is the content to show for 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try with adding `parent()`

```
$(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Bootstrap to achieve this, just try below code.

```
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <br>
  <a href="#"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Item #1</a>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
   Collapsible Group Item #1
  </div>

   <br> <br>
 <a href="#"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Item #2</a>
  <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
  Collapsible Group Item #2
  </div>

    <br> <br>
   <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3">Item #3</a>  
  <div id="demo3" class="collapse">
  Collapsible Group Item #3
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```